# how to check for a maximum/minimum value in a document in Marklogic using xquery?

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to find out how to check for a maximum/minimum value for a timestamp attribute in a document.

sample document would be something like :

uri 1 data:

```
{
createdTime:2018-10-22 10:04:00
filename: employee.txt
}
```

uri 2 data:

```
{
createdTime:2018-10-22 11:04:00
filename: employee.txt
}
```

All I need is to see the minimum creation date for the file employee.txt. How do I write an XQuery for the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You could [apply a range inde](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_51346)x on createdTime, if you are able to make the createdTime comply to the `xs:dateTime` format (which basically means replacing the space between date and time with the character 'T' in your case), by adjusting your data.

If so, you can use functions like [`cts.min`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.min), and [`cts.max`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.max) to fetch minimum and maximum values for that property.

If not, you could try brute-force by getting all values, sorting them as strings, and then grabbing first and last, but that is generally not very wise, since that scales terribly.

If you can't change your data, and brute-force is no option either, you could consider looking into using [Template Driven Extraction](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE). That is a fairly advanced topic though, and might make things more complicated than necessary.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks. I have a range index on that column and the datetime format also has a T to the value. But using cts.min and cts.max can be done only for numeric values.

Comment: I am trying a different approach using a for loop and order by .. Will post my answer once i am done :) Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Min and max should work for string, numeric, and almost all date related types. Did you try?

Comment: cts.min and cts.max take a cts.reference as a parameter, which is an ordered index. It should work fine for dates and will be *much* faster than any loop-based approach.

Comment: For JSON you'd use a [cts.jsonPropertyReference](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyReference). MarkLogic is usually fairly smart at discovering type and collation automatically, but if needed you can pass those in explicitly as option into those references as well..

Answer (score 0):

Poster asked for an Xquery.  THat is simple enough.

```
min(doc("file.json")//createdTime)
```

If the json field (string) is formatted as shown then it does not need to be converted to a dateTime -- as text lexical sorting order produces the same order for this format.  Otherwise you will need to parse and convert to xs:dateTime